# Can proofs be written entirely without words and are there any non-trivial examples in the literature?

Tags: proof-writing, publishing

**Can proofs be written entirely without words and are there any non-trivial examples in the literature?**

The title and abstract may contain words but the proof should not. I am not a mathematician but have an amateur interest.

**Question**

Is mathematical symbolism complete enough to write an entire proof of a non-trivial theorem without a single word? Has anyone ever published such a proof in a recognised journal?

If you wish me to be more specific, please assume that I'm asking about mature subjects such as calculus and number theory.

Comment: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_proof

Comment: You might also be interested in the flip-side of this, namely, omitting the standard symbolism altogether and just doing the mathematical thinking using familiar objects. Here is the link to a site where this is discussed, and implemented, via video-gaming-type software: https://brainquake.medium.com/solving-the-ultimate-math-problem-b96597fc3534

Comment: My professor required us to learn to write the standard proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational without words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Bertrand Russell's Principia Mathematica has lots of proofs written in symbolic logic.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica